# How to do a Bspline image interpolation (2D/3D) using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, bspline

I am looking for a **differentiable** Bspline image interpolation implementation using Matlab. The build-in functions in Matlab can not interpolate the image with a differentiable interpolation.

```
interp2(ix, iy, image, ixt, iyt, 'linear', 0);
interp2(ix, iy, image, ixt, iyt, 'spline', 0);
```

Also the IMTRANSFORM is not capable of doing Bspline interpolation.

Any ideas please tell me. Thanks,
Aaronne.